# JavaScript and "onclickstart"

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've searched a lot for a JavaScript event which shows a situation
that a click has been started but not finished yet. For example for
`ondrag` event there's an `ondragstart`. I didn't find anything useful.

So here's the question:

Is there a `onclickstart` event in JavaScript?
If the answer is "No", how could it be implemented?

I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for `onmousedown`.  Check out [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onmousedown):

Comment: @Zenith What's the rationale behind the anti-w3schools subculture here?

Comment: @svidgen http://w3fools.com/ is one reason. For basic HTML/CSS stuff it's fine, but for JavaScript/PHP etc, if you can find a link to a better resource, it's always better to post that

Comment: @Zenith Unfortunately doing a google for "onmousedown" returns the w3schools link as the #1 hit so I just grabbed that. It's not inaccurate, but if it makes you feel better I updated the link to point to a mozilla reference instead.

Comment: @Zenith Not that I'm going to lay myself down for any web-tech reference, but this is incredibly vague criticism of a tutorial-oriented site, of which there are many far worse than w3schools. The objection seems more political than anything ...

Comment: @svidgen Political? What makes you say that?

Comment: @clav Don't worry so much, I had already upvoted your answer even with the link :)

Comment: @Zenith It's vague, un-constructive, and the real objection is obvious (w3schools is for-profit and not "open content"), but not directly stated.

Comment: @Zenith More importantly, the linked-to page was accurate. If the resource is accurate, why object?

Comment: @svidgen I don't see any comment where I 'objected' to it? I simply said it's not the best resource. I upvoted the answer anyway like I've already stated.

Comment: @Zenith Yeah, your comment was more silly in tone than serious, hence, I'd figured you/now would be a good time to ask why this anti-w3schools subculture exists -- I've seen and gotten rude comments for linking to it. And, I was curious as to whether there was any *serious*, identifiable problem with the resource ... not yet convinced there is. (No more than any other equally fallible resource, anyway.)

Comment: @svidgen let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30277/discussion-between-zenith-and-svidgen)

Comment: For anyone who cares, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp) is the w3schools link again.  I find w3schools more helpful because it gives actual examples of code and warns you if syntax is not cross-browser which developer.mozilla.org does not.  This may not be necessary for advanced users, but you can't assume that everyone reading this post is an advanced user.